# Angular - Check if value entered into a field is a number

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app I have a field that accepts either an email address or a phone number.

If a number is entered I want to show a particular span. However I can't seem to get this working.

So in my controller I have written:

```
$scope.isNumber = function (n) {
     return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Then in my HTML I have:

```
<form name="registrationForm">

<div>
   Email or Mobile
   <span ng-show="isNumber(registrationForm.usernameReg)">Include the country code.</span>
</div>

<input name="usernameReg" ng-change="main.change()" type="text" ng-model="main.username">

</form>
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: my mobile looks lie +33 (0)4... Don't use parseFloat() to check if something is a phone number: a phone number is not a floating point value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be testing the value of the model.

try

```
ng-show="isNumber(main.username)"
```

`registrationForm.usernameReg` is an object that contains numerous properties used as part of validation.

To better see this add `<pre>{{registrationForm |json}}</pre>` in your view

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but the when I do a console.log of the value coming in it gives `undefined`

Comment: Create a plunker demo. Will be undefined if not predefined in controller or until user enters something

Comment: Yep - thats what I thought however even when I type something in, it continues to say `undefined`

Comment: Works fine here entering only digits http://plnkr.co/edit/n2NPbZ765qAMvMuFlZtJ?p=preview

Comment: Could you share with us your console.log ?

Comment: All ok - I had some validation code that was blocking.